# Find string in file then delete

Tags: string, grep

I am trying to find a particular string in files on my server. I have done the following which gives me a list of files, but how do I now delete them?

```
grep -H -r "example" /home/72754/domains | cut -d: -f1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this if you want to delete files:

```
grep -l -r "example" /home/72754/domains | xargs rm
```

Comment: If you just want to delete strings from files use other answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed` with the same pattern and change what you want

If you want to delete the whole line then something like this

```
sed '/example/d' /home/72754/domains
```

And to update the same file, use the `-i` flag

If you want to update a certain pattern, you can use something like this

```
sed 's/password/****/' /file
```

And again you can use the `-i` flag to update and overwrite the file